# PHP preg_replace: Case insensitive match with case sensitive replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using preg_replace in PHP to find and replace specific words in a string, like this:

```
$subject = "Apple apple";
print preg_replace('/\bapple\b/i', 'pear', $subject);
```

Which gives the result 'pear pear'.

What I'd like to be able to do is to match a word in a case insensitive way, but respect it's case when it is replaced - giving the result 'Pear pear'.

The following works, but seems a little long winded to me:

```
$pattern = array('/Apple\b/', '/apple\b/');
$replacement = array('Pear', 'pear');
$subject = "Apple apple";
print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Update: Further to an excellent query raised below, for the purposes of this task I only want to respect 'title case' - so whether or not the first letter of a word is a capital.

Comment: The only thing that remains unclear: what if your replacement and original word have different length and original word has capital letter at higher position? I.e. `'applE'` and `'pear'` what then?

Comment: Excellent point. For the purposes of this particular task, I'd only want to respect 'title case' (so whether or not the first letter is a capital). Thanks so much for adding further clarity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have in mind this implementation for common case:

```
$data    = 'this is appLe and ApPle';
$search  = 'apple';
$replace = 'pear';

$data = preg_replace_callback('/\b'.$search.'\b/i', function($matches) use ($replace)
{
   $i=0;
   return join('', array_map(function($char) use ($matches, &$i)
   {
      return ctype_lower($matches[0][$i++])?strtolower($char):strtoupper($char);
   }, str_split($replace)));
}, $data);

//var_dump($data); //"this is peaR and PeAr"
```

-it's more complicated, of course, but fit original request for any position. If you're looking for only first letter, this could be an overkill (see @Jon's answer then)

Answer (score 12):

You could do this with `preg_replace_callback`, but that's even more long winded:

```
$replacer = function($matches) {
    return ctype_lower($matches[0][0]) ? 'pear' : 'Pear';
};

print preg_replace_callback('/\bapple\b/i', $replacer, $subject);
```

This code just looks at the capitalization of the first character of the match to determine what to replace with; you could adapt the code to do something more involved instead.

Comment: I tried your code, but i get Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string...

Comment: @c3cris I had mistakenly written just `preg_replace` instead of `preg_replace_callback` in the snippet above, even though the mention in the first line was correct. Fixed.

Comment: This is a far more elegant solution. Much shorter and simpler to understand at a glance. +1

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution that I used:

```
$result = preg_replace("/\b(foo)\b/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $original);
```

In the best words that I can I'll try explain why this works: Wrapping your search term with `()` means I want to access this value later. As it is the first item in pars in the RegEx, it is accessible with `$1`, as you can see in the substitution parameter

Comment: And look at the difference between that and the expected answer. A great reminder to all engineers to "keep it simple".

Comment: This answer fails to provide the expected result/functionality.

Comment: So simple! How had I forgotten about back referencing? Thank you!

Comment: It's $1 or $0 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'Grey, grey and grey';
$text = Find_and_replace_in_lowercase_and_uppercase('grey', 'gray', $text);
echo $text; //Returns 'Gray, gray and gray'

function Find_and_replace_in_lowercase_and_uppercase($find_term, $replace_term, $text)
{
        $text = Find_and_replace_in_lowercase($find_term, $replace_term, $text);
        $text = Find_and_replace_in_uppercase($find_term, $replace_term, $text);
        return $text;

}
function Find_and_replace_in_lowercase($find_term, $replace_term, $text)
{
        $find_term = lcfirst($find_term);
        $replace_term = lcfirst($replace_term);
        $text = preg_replace("/$find_term/",$replace_term,$text);
        return $text;
}
function Find_and_replace_in_uppercase($find_term, $replace_term, $text)
{
        $find_term = ucfirst($find_term);
        $replace_term = ucfirst($replace_term);
        $text = preg_replace("/$find_term/",$replace_term,$text);
        return $text;
}
```