# Find and Replace Words in Post Content For Specific Category

Tags: wordpress

I have tried my best. but it is still giving me blank page. My goal is to Find and Replace words in post content article for one or two specific category, Not the entire site.

```
function specific_category_postsfilter($content) {

    if (is_single() && in_category('Uncategorized')) {
        $old_word = 'Listen Below';
    $new_word = 'Just Now';
    str_replace($old_word, $new_word, $content);
    }
}
     add_filter('the_content', 'specific_category_postsfilter');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually pretty close! If you look at the docs for [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter, (actually any filter, for that matter) you'll see that it requires the filtered values to be `returned`.

Also if you look at the docs for [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) you'll see that you need to do something with the returned value.

So, with those in mind we can change it to `str_replace` the words in `$content` only if it's a single post in 'Uncategorized', and then always return the `$content` afterwards, modified or unmodified:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_content_in_category' );
function replace_content_in_category( $content ){
    if( is_single() && in_category( 'Uncategorized' ) ){
        $old_word = 'Listen Below';
        $new_word = 'Just Now';

        $content = str_replace( $old_word, $new_word, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT. THIS WORKS LIKE CHARM... please mark as answered

Comment: Marking as answered is actually something you have to do as the original question asker :) - just click on the check mark next to the arrows on the answer. Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks alot, Please take a view of this Post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50983378/4881307